# What are all the order types of maximal chains of $\Delta^0_2$ sets?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, order-theory, linear-orders, turing-degrees

A set of natural numbers is $\Delta^0_2$ if it’s computable from the halting set.  Consider the quasi-order/pre-order of all $\Delta_0^2$ sets ordered by $m$-reduction, or equivalently consider the partial order of all $m$-degrees of $\Delta^0_2$ sets.  My question is, what order types can maximal chains of this order have?  That is, what are the order types of maximal linearly ordered collections $C$ of $\Delta^0_2$ sets such that for all $A,B\in C$, either $A=B$, $A<_mB$, or $B<_mA$?

Yuri Ershov, in his work on the Ershov hierarchy, showed that there are maximal chains of order type $\omega^3$ and $\omega_1^{CK}$.  He also showed that there are non-maximal chains of order type $\eta$, the order type of the rationals, which implies that every countable linear order can be embedded in a chain of $\Delta^0_2$ sets.  But what order type can maximal chains have?  Can they have order type $\alpha$ for any limit ordinal $\omega^3\leq\alpha\leq\omega_1^{CK}$?  I’m particularly interested in non-well-ordered order types.  For instance can they have order type $\omega_1^{CK}(1+\eta)$, the order type of the Harrison ordering?

Would the answer change if we restricted ourselves to arithmetically definable maximal chains?